# Performance & Browser Support Considerations for CSS-blurred Video

Tags: html, css, performance, accessibility

I am currently working on a site who's requirements are to include a full size blurred background video using css ([like this codepen](http://codepen.io/Ashugeo/pen/bVbyNE)):

```
.video-back {
  -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
  -moz-filter: blur(15px);
  -o-filter: blur(15px);
  -ms-filter: blur(15px);
  filter: blur(15px);
}
```

I've tested it on modern browsers and it seems like the blur functions on modern FF, Chrome, Opera, & Safari. I will be gracefully degrading the video into a large splash image for tablet, mobile, and IE.

My main question is: are there any other factors I may be missing? computer RAM or graphics processing ability? Older versions of browsers that are still common?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link can help you! this page make a benchmark with some filters and see the performance with and without the filter blur on

http://blog.kaelig.fr/post/47025488367/css-filters-in-the-real-world